# Hierarchy from Flat Data w/ out parentID childID

Tags: c#, hierarchy

```
| Level1      | Level2               | Level3       | Level4|

| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | NULL         | NULL  |

| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |

| ELECTRONICS | PC                   | NULL         | NULL  |

| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |

| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |

| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
```

In a legacy database I have this table, I am trying to print it out in a nice hierarchy html ul li list. I have been trying different answers here on stackoverflow to build the objects in C# but they all have parentID and childID and that dosent work for me in this case.

I am trying this code, but I do understand that it is really bad,

```
    List<Node> FlatToHierarchy(IList<SearchWord> list)
    {
        List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();

        foreach (SearchWord x in list)
        {
            if (x.Level2 != " " && x.Level3 == " ")
            {
                Node node = new Node();
                node.Parent = x.Level1;
                node.Child = x.Level2;
                node.Keyword = x.Keyword;
                nodes.Add(node);
                //dict.Add(node.Parent, node);
            }

            if (x.Level3 != " " && x.Level4 == " ")
            {
                Node node = new Node();
                node.Parent = x.Level2;
                node.Child = x.Level3;
                node.Keyword = x.Keyword;
                nodes.Add(node);
                //dict.Add(node.Parent, node);
            }

            if (x.Level4 != " ")
            {
                Node node = new Node();
                node.Parent = x.Level3;
                node.Child = x.Level4;
                node.Keyword = x.Keyword;
                nodes.Add(node);
                //dict.Add(node.Parent, node);
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
```

Comment: why not build a heirarchy out of the flat data and then use that to build your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build a true hierarchy, your `class Node` will need to have the sub-items in the class. Add `List<Node>` into `Node` as well as an `Add` method, so the data contains the hierarchy. Then you can build an html li/ul list. For example, the `Node` class might look like:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Current node name
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; } // Optional

    private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();
    public List<Node> Children { get { return _children; } }

    public Node AddChild(Node child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
        return this;
    }   
}
```

Or you could make `Parent` a reference to a Node:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get { Parent != null ? Parent.Name : null; } }
    // ...
}
```

Then to build the html li/ul list, you recursively iterate through the Node structure.

EDIT: Actually, now that I think of it, you might just want to build a hierarchical XML document from the data. Then you can build the ul/li from xml:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Level1 { get; set; }
    public string Level2 { get; set; }
    public string Level3 { get; set; }
    public string Level4 { get; set; }
}

public Data[] sampleData = new Data[] {
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "TELEVISIONS", Level3 = null, Level4 = null },
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "TELEVISIONS", Level3 = "LCD", Level4 = null },
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "PC", Level3 = null, Level4 = null },
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", Level3 = "MP3 PLAYERS", Level4 = "FLASH" },
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", Level3 = "CD PLAYERS", Level4 = null },
    new Data { Level1 = "ELECTRONICS", Level2 = "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", Level3 = "2 WAY RADIOS", Level4 = null },
};

XElement AddNode(string name)
{
    return new XElement("Node", 
        new XAttribute("Name", name));
}

// NOTE: This is not optimized, but you get the idea...
XDocument BuildHierarchy(IEnumerable<Data> data)
{
    XElement root = new XElement("Root");
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(root);
    XElement level1 = null;
    XElement level2 = null;
    XElement level3 = null;
    XElement level4 = null;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        // Assumes item.Level1 is never empty...
        if (level1 == null || string.Compare(item.Level1, level1.Attribute("Name").Value) != 0)
        {
            level1 = AddNode(item.Level1);
            root.Add(level1);
            level2 = null;
            level3 = null;
            level4 = null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Level2))
        {
            level2 = null;
            level3 = null;
            level4 = null;
            continue;
        }

        if (level2 == null || string.Compare(item.Level2, level2.Attribute("Name").Value) != 0)
        {
            level2 = AddNode(item.Level2);
            level1.Add(level2);
            level3 = null;
            level4 = null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Level3))
        {
            level2 = null;
            level3 = null;
            level4 = null;
            continue;
        }

        if (level3 == null || string.Compare(item.Level3, level3.Attribute("Name").Value) != 0)
        {
            level3 = AddNode(item.Level3);
            level2.Add(level3);
            level4 = null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Level4))
        {
            level4 = null;
            continue;
        }

        if (level4 == null || string.Compare(item.Level4, level4.Attribute("Name").Value) != 0)
        {
            level4 = AddNode(item.Level4);
            level3.Add(level4);
        }
    }

    return xdoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take this table into a collection of rows and group the rows on each column, but it depends on the data structure you want to end up with.

If all you require is a hierarchical list in HTML and it's only 4 columns, do a database query sorted on `Level1`, `Level2`, `Level3`, `Level4` accordingly, then loop through them. Keep an indicator to see if the level changed and output HTML code as required.